# Mysql - Select distinct column with column id query is not working

Tags: mysql

i have few duplicate rows in my mysql table which belongs to different different categories , my table structure is like this .

```
sample_table
-----------------------
id | title | category
-----------------------
1  |item 1 | category 1
2  |item 1 | category 2
3  |item 1 | category 3
4  |item 2 | category 1
5  |item 2 | category 3
```

my problem is I want distinct title column from my table along with their id ,I tried `select distinct title from sample_table`,it returns 2 rows,
but if i try `select distinct title , id from sample_table` it returns all 5 rows.

Now my problem is I want distinct title with their id's from table i.e 2 rows with their id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group by

```
select id,title from sample_table group by title
```

Comment: As id is not in group by list, this query would be rejected in MySQL v5.7.5 or above unless you choose special setup configuration see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Use instead select with a group by statement like that :

```
select title, group_concat(id separator ' ') as ids 
from sample_table 
group by title;
```

it will return 2 rows like that :

```
title ids
item1 1 2 3
item2 4 5
```